# Make a dictionary on matching values

Tags: python

I am having some trouble making dictionaries based on multiple matches in a list.

Here is a sample list:

```
items = [["1.pdf", "123", "train", "plaza"],
         ["2.pdf","123", "plane", "town"],
         ["3.pdf", "456", "train", "plaza"],
         ["4.pdf", "123", "plane", "city"],
         ["5.pdf", "123", "train", "plaza"],
         ["6.pdf","123", "plane", "town"]]
```

What I am attempting to do is match on the last three items in each list and make a dictionary.

So based on the list above I would assume the desired output would be.

```
{1 : [["1.pdf", "123", "train", "plaza"],
      ["5.pdf", "123", "train", "plaza"]],
 2 : [["2.pdf","123", "plane", "town"],
      ["6.pdf","123", "plane", "town"]]
 3 : [["3.pdf", "456", "train", "plaza"]]
 4 : [["4.pdf", "123", "plane", "city"]]}
```

Comment: Do you have an initial attempt you could show us?

Comment: Why not a list of lists? You are using sequential numbers for the keys, after all.

Comment: From what data do you build the dictionary keys?

Comment: @Howard I get the values from a csv.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I dont use lists because the first item is the list is an image file so I build a dictionary together so I know which ones to combine on the key.

Comment: @sihrc The only thing I was able to do was build a dictionary on one value.

    for i in lists:
        k = i[1]
        if k in collection:
            collection[k].append(i)
        else:
            collection[k] = [i]
    return collection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might I suggest a different output data format?

```
from collections import *
d = defaultdict(list)

for item in items:
    d[tuple(item[1:])].append(item[0])
```

This results in a dict like:

```
{
    ('123', 'train', 'plaza'): ['1.pdf', '5.pdf'],
    ('123', 'plane', 'town'):  ['2.pdf', '6.pdf'],
    ('123', 'plane', 'city'):  ['4.pdf'],
    ('456', 'train', 'plaza'): ['3.pdf']
}
```

Comment: I like this way and would work, but how would I go about doing it if the indices are are in order? Example item[0], item[3], item[4]

Comment: Sorry if that question wasn't stated in the top question.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore my bad naming schemes.

```
items = [["1.pdf", "123", "train", "plaza"],
         ["2.pdf","123", "plane", "town"],
         ["3.pdf", "456", "train", "plaza"],
         ["4.pdf", "123", "plane", "city"],
         ["5.pdf", "123", "train", "plaza"],
         ["6.pdf","123", "plane", "town"]]

final = dict()
for item in items:
    final[tuple(item[1:])] = final.get(tuple(item[1:]),[]) + [item]

new = dict()
for i in range(len(final)):
    new[i+1] = final.items()[i][1]

for key,items in new.items():
    print key, ":\n",items
```

Yields (Random Order):

```
{1 : [["1.pdf", "123", "train", "plaza"],
      ["5.pdf", "123", "train", "plaza"]],
 2 : [["2.pdf","123", "plane", "town"],
      ["6.pdf","123", "plane", "town"]]
 3 : [["3.pdf", "456", "train", "plaza"]]
 4 : [["4.pdf", "123", "plane", "city"]]}
```

Comment: A tuple can be used a key instead of `str(item[1:])` and `enumerate` is better than `range(len(final))`.

Comment: Note that using a normal dict the order of output can be arbitrary, so it won't match OP's expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
for item in items:
    dic[tuple(item[1:])].append(item)
...     
>>> ans = { i: item for i, item in enumerate(dic.values(), 1)}
>>> pprint(ans)
{1: [['1.pdf', '123', 'train', 'plaza'], ['5.pdf', '123', 'train', 'plaza']],
 2: [['2.pdf', '123', 'plane', 'town'], ['6.pdf', '123', 'plane', 'town']],
 3: [['4.pdf', '123', 'plane', 'city']],
 4: [['3.pdf', '456', 'train', 'plaza']]}
```

If order matters then use `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dic = OrderedDict()
for item in items:                                        
    dic.setdefault(tuple(item[1:]), []).append(item)
...     
>>> ans = { i: item for i, item in enumerate(dic.values(), 1)}
>>> pprint(ans)
{1: [['1.pdf', '123', 'train', 'plaza'], ['5.pdf', '123', 'train', 'plaza']],
 2: [['2.pdf', '123', 'plane', 'town'], ['6.pdf', '123', 'plane', 'town']],
 3: [['3.pdf', '456', 'train', 'plaza']],
 4: [['4.pdf', '123', 'plane', 'city']]}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `groupby` operation. If you are using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
In [2]: items
Out[2]: 
[['1.pdf', '123', 'train', 'plaza'],
 ['2.pdf', '123', 'plane', 'town'],
 ['3.pdf', '456', 'train', 'plaza'],
 ['4.pdf', '123', 'plane', 'city'],
 ['5.pdf', '123', 'train', 'plaza'],
 ['6.pdf', '123', 'plane', 'town']]

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(items)

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
       0    1      2      3
0  1.pdf  123  train  plaza
1  2.pdf  123  plane   town
2  3.pdf  456  train  plaza
3  4.pdf  123  plane   city
4  5.pdf  123  train  plaza
5  6.pdf  123  plane   town


In [5]: for n, g in df.groupby([1, 2, 3]):
    print "name", n
    print g
   ....:     
name ('123', 'plane', 'city')
       0    1      2     3
3  4.pdf  123  plane  city
name ('123', 'plane', 'town')
       0    1      2     3
1  2.pdf  123  plane  town
5  6.pdf  123  plane  town
name ('123', 'train', 'plaza')
       0    1      2      3
0  1.pdf  123  train  plaza
4  5.pdf  123  train  plaza
name ('456', 'train', 'plaza')
       0    1      2      3
2  3.pdf  456  train  plaza
```